# how to remove the spaces in db data when comparing with input data in codeigniter 3 active record?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

if the input data got no beginning nor trailing spaces and the db data got a trailing space, how to remove the db data trailing space in order match the input data? how to do it in the active record of codeigniter 3 ?

e.g

```
$this->db->where('name_column', $inputdata);
```

the db data held by that name_column has trailing spaces or at the beginning, how to remove that in that active record query above? because it will not match even if I do some validation in the input data

e.g `$this->db->where('name_column', trim($inputdata);`

Comment: Just being persnickety, but Active Record is gone. It's called Query Builder in CI v 3.x  :)

Comment: user TRIM of mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the sql string function `TRIM` in the where statement.

Because this example writes out the whole WHERE clause manually we trim the input before using it in the `where` call.

```
$inputdata = trim($inputdata);
$this->db->where("TRIM('name_column') = $inputdata", NULL, FALSE);
```

The last param (FALSE) turns off escaping of values and identifiers. That is necessary because `TRIM(('name_column')` will almost certainly be incorrectly escaped and break the SQL syntax.